# Same account different different status then other else same status . How to do this in T-SQl

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Same account different different status then other else same status . How to do this in T-SQl

```
Account Status
1000001185  A
1000001185  E 
1000001185  E 
1000001185  D
1000001777  E 
1000001777  E 
1000001777  E 
1000001185  E
```

Comment: What results are you looking for?

Comment: Expected Result Account 1000001185 is others  and Account 1000001777 is 'E'

Comment: So, just to paraphrase - If a given account has multiple distinct statuses you want to return {AccountNumber, 'other'}, otherwise you want {AccountNumber,Status}?

Comment: Please clarify "Same account different different status".

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
select Account, (case when min(Status) = max(Status) 
                      then min(Status) 
                      else 'other' 
                  end)
from table t
group by Account;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/23699) is a SQL Fiddle showing that this solution is correct.

Comment: No. Not getting result

Comment: @TRam . . . This query should be doing exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this i used Lead () Function

```
;WITH CTE(Account, [Status])
AS
(
SELECT '1000001185','A' UNION ALL
SELECT '1000001185','E' UNION ALL 
SELECT '1000001185','E' UNION ALL 
SELECT '1000001185','D' UNION ALL
SELECT '1000001777','E' UNION ALL 
SELECT '1000001777','E' UNION ALL 
SELECT '1000001777','E' UNION ALL 
SELECT '1000001185','E' 
)
SELECT Account,[Status],CASE WHEN [Status]<>LEAD([Status],1)OVER(PARTITION BY Account ORDER BY Account)
            THEN 'Other' ELSE [Status] END [NewStatus]
 FROM Cte 

 ORDER BY cte.[Status]
```

Result

```
 Account    Status       NewStatus
 -------------------------------------
1000001185      A           A
1000001185      D           Other
1000001185      E           Other
1000001185      E           E
1000001185      E           Other
1000001777      E           E
1000001777      E           E
1000001777      E           E
```